# .Item property of readOnlycollection doesn't work

Tags: python, vb.net, readonly-collection

Im making a project in Python, using CPython3.4. I imported a dll which contains a ReadOnlyCollection. How can I get one item(at index) out of that list? I already tried to use .Item(index) and .Items but it says that:

"the object has no attribute "Item"

But when I use .Count it does give me the count. And the documentation says I could use both on this object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx The dll is written in VB.net.

Can someone help me get one item out of that ReadOnlyCollection?

Comment: According to MSDN, ReadOnlyCollection.Items returns a List(of T).  Since Items is the list in question,  have you tried ReadOnlyCollection.Items.Item(index)?  Long-winded, and shouldn't be necessary, but worth a try.

Comment: Just tried that, unfortunately that didn't work either :(, thx for helping anyway

Comment: Perhaps post your Python code where you're instantiating the collection itself, because it sounds like something is null that shouldn't be.  I won't be able to help there, as I'm not a Python programmer, but I'm sure someone with knowledge of Python will be along soon.

Comment: I could do that but im pretty sure I did that right, because when I call the collection.Count it gives me the correct awnser. So that means I'm sure something is in the list :)

Comment: @RowanKleinGunnewiek how about `myReadOnlyCollection[i]`? (`i` is index of the item) that is the syntax in C#, may be the same for python

Comment: @har07 I already tried that, then I get the error : TypeError: unindexable object. So unfortunately that doesn't work :(, and when I try     myReadOnlyCollection( i )  then i get the error: object is not callable

Comment: @har07 Could you take a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538031/call-dll-function-works-in-ironpython-doesnt-work-in-cpython3-4-gives-no-meth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this possible?

```
for i in ReadOnlyCollection:
    i.doSomething()
```

If it is possible you can find your object in this loop

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you!, This is a way around it but it worked!